# How to apply styles for vaadin tooltip overlay only for certain components?

Tags: vaadin

I have a Vaadin 23 Application and the following code for setting a tooltip to a text area:

```
textAreaDescription = UiFactory.createTextArea();
textAreaDescription.setClassName("sp-tooltip");
 
Tooltip tooltip = Tooltip.forComponent(textAreaDescription)
         .withText(textAreaDescription.getValue())
         .withPosition(Tooltip.TooltipPosition.TOP_START);
```

This is the vaadin-tooltip-overlay.css

```
:host(.sp-tooltip) [part="overlay"] {
   width: 80em !important;
   height: 30em !important;
   color: #c9c9c9;
   background-color: #474747;
   white-space: pre-line;
}
```

That does not seem to work. If I remove the (.sp-tooltip) from the overlay then I can see the changes takin effect but I only want to apply this to components with the sp-tooltip set. I cannot set a class to the tooltip itself or get the element, so how can I achieve this?

Thanks and Best Regards
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is simply not available in Tooltip Java API yet](https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/4482). But one can do this with a JavaScript call, which is not entirely straightforward as there are two options where the `vaadin-tooltip` element actually is.

If one uses `textField.setTooltipText("Tooltip text")` API, the element is placed in tooltip slot inside TextField itself. But if you use `Tooltip tooltip = Tooltip.forComponent(textField).withText("Tooltip text")` the tooltip element is child of the document and mapped by id. So the JavaScript needs to take the both options into account. Here is generally usable utility function for the task.

```
public static void setTooltipClassName(Component comp, String className) {
    comp.getElement().executeJs(
    """
        if ($0.getElementsByTagName('vaadin-tooltip').length == 1) {
            $0.getElementsByTagName('vaadin-tooltip')[0]._overlayElement.setAttribute('class',$1);
        } else {
            const tooltips = document.getElementsByTagName('vaadin-tooltip');
            for (let i=0; i<tooltips.length; i++ ) {
                const tooltip = tooltips[i];
                if (tooltip._overlayElement.id === $0.getAttribute('aria-describedBy')) {
                    tooltip._overlayElement.setAttribute('class',$1)
                }
            }
        }
     """, comp.getElement(), className);
}
```